# Why is it that when iType in recyclervieew searchview the app closes

Tags: android-recyclerview, searchview

My app crashes and closes as I type in searchview. Shall share the code later.
Anybody?

My app is closing ss i start typing in searchview. Im taking data from string.xml
I have an adapter class, model class, Do i have to ser right my ids ..no idea

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a recycler view taking data from string.xml and is working fine. But when I create a searchview it crashes and closes my app the moment I type in it. Is there a problem in code. Can I share whole code: